# How to insert a Data Row in the first line in a DataTable?

Tags: list, flutter, datatable, datarow

i have a DataTable, where i want to add Rows. The Code works, but the Data Row gets add below the last Data Row. I want to add a Row at the top. I used list.insert(0, element) but it didnt work.

This is my Code so far:

```
class _TabelleState extends State<Tabelle> {

  List<DataRow> _rowList = [
    DataRow(
        cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Datum()),
      DataCell(UebungWidget()),
      DataCell(UebungWidget()),
      DataCell(UebungWidget()),
    ]),
  ];
  
  void _addRow() {
    setState(() {
      _rowList.insert(0, (DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Datum()),
        DataCell(UebungWidget()),
        DataCell(UebungWidget()),
        DataCell(UebungWidget()),
      ])));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the approach you are using should work as expected. Nevertheless, if you are populating your `DataCell`s with `TextField`s, in that case you will have to add a `GlobalKey` to ***each*** `TextField`, so that **Flutter** knows where each `DataCell` belongs.

For more info on `Keys` watch [this Flutter mini-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc).

Please try the following complete running sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tabelle(); 
  }
}

class Tabelle extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabelleState createState() => _TabelleState();
}

class _TabelleState extends State<Tabelle> {

  List<DataRow> _rowList = [
    DataRow(
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
          DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
          DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
          DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
        ]),
  ];

  void _addRow() {
    setState(() {
      _rowList.insert(0, (DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
            DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
            DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
            DataCell(TextField(key: GlobalKey(),)),
          ])));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Plan'), actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _addRow,
          child: Text(
            'Neues Training',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable(
                dataRowHeight: 200,
                headingRowColor:
                MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.black26),
                dataRowColor:
                MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.black26),
                columnSpacing: 20,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('seconds', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Datum', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Datum', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Datum', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),)),
                ], rows: _rowList),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, i compared it to my code and didnt found the mistake. Do you know why my insert function dont work?

Comment: @Dalon As you yourself have noted, your code looks just ok. If you still have problems it would be great if you could post more code, to see some context. Maybe also the datatable declaration? Is there some sorting?

Comment: @Dalon, i am running the code you posted and it adds the rows at the start of the datatable, not at the end...

Comment: When i use TextField() in the DataCells it didnt work, but when i just use a Text() it works. How can i fix that?

Comment: The TextField() Widget dont move like the other Widgets in the Cells... I dont know why. Its like they stuck

Comment: @Dalon, add GlobalKeys on each TextField. Please see my updated answer for further details.

Comment: @Dalon, did adding keys solved your problem?